# toString() and MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, tostring, presentation

The API documentation for `toString()` states:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. **The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read.** It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.

(emphasis mine)

With that in mind, I wrote a `toString()` for a `Building` type class that was essentially (some implementation stripped)

```
@Override
public String toString(){
Stringbuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<p>");
sb.append (this.getDesc());
sb.append ("which contains: <br> <ul>"); 
for (Room r: this.getRooms()){
    sb.append("<li>");
    sb.append(r.getDesc());
    sb.append("</li>");
}
sb.append("</ul>");
return sb.toString();
}
```

Giving something like:

> A self contained student flat which contains:
>
> - A basic study
> - A basic living area
> - A basic bathroom
> - A basic bedroom

I think this is a "concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read" but it seems to fly in the face of MVC as I understand it.  The `Building` and `Room` class are both in the Model and surely that sort of output formatting belongs in the view?

I'm not certain whether I'm overthinking this, whether the Java API isn't written with MVC in mind or whether there's something I haven't understood.  Can presentation matters go in the `toString()`?  Would I be better having a seperate `displayBuilding()` or similar?

Comment: You could theoretically also use typeclasses and provide an implementation for the `Show` typeclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO `Object::toString` is very useful in logs and debugging, So, I'd use plain text to render its output.

My suggestions are:

- Use libraries such as [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and method `ReflectionToStringBuilder::toString` to quickly get a plain text output.
- Create a functional interface (e.g. `HtmlRepresentable`) with one method `toHtmlString` implement such method in your classes you want to have an HTML object representation.

  ```
  public interface HtmlRepresentable {
      String toHtmlString();
  }
  ```

  Then

  ```
  public Building implements HtmlRepresentable {

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<p>");
          sb.append (this.getDesc());
          sb.append ("which contains: <br> <ul>"); 
          for (Room r: this.getRooms()) {
              sb.append("<li>" + r.getDesc() + "</li>");
          }
          sb.append("</ul>");
          return sb.toString(); 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

`toString()` is mostly used as a tool in java world for debugging or displaying data in the log.

For the purpose mentioned by you, it is very much clear that `toString()` is definitely not the tool.

You should be very specific on the data that has to be displayed in the view and may be use a different model all together and then set values in that from the Building model and then send that model to UI.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `toString()` to produce HTML code for your view. This is not the intended use of the `toString()` method. I think, it is mainly intended to produce debugging information e.g. for use in logfiles or in the debugger. This is meant by "easy for a person to read". HTML is a more technical representation for being included in the webpage. The name of such a method would rather be something like `render()`.